# What exactly setenv.sh is used for in Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, credentials

I searched a lot but couldn't find any useful information about this:

**What exactly** *setenv.sh* **is used for in Tomcat ?**

Let's say we have a REST API (built with Java EE or Spring) which uses some parameters/variables like AWS Credentials, Database Credentials etc.

Does it make sense to parametrize the application with environment variables for these things I mentioned above and put their values to env vars on *setenv.sh* for each Tomcat instance in case we use more than one instance and with different parameters/variables ?

Or *setenv.sh* isn't for things like that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've only ever seen it used for specifying `CATALINA_OPTS`, but I noticed that the [RUNNING.txt](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) file mentions using it to set `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`.

[RUNNING.txt](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) also states under *Advanced Configuration - Multiple Tomcat Instances*:

> In many circumstances, it is desirable to have a single copy of a
>   Tomcat binary distribution shared among multiple users on the same
>   server.  To make this possible, you can set the CATALINA_BASE
>   environment variable to the directory that contains the files for your
>   'personal' Tomcat instance.

So I guess the answer is that a `setenv` file can be created for each app and can probably can be used to store credentials, but I don't think that it's commonly used for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

~/Programs/apache-tomcat-9.0.7/bin/setenv.sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -DENV_TARGET=prod -DMy_Env_Var1=Whatever -DMy_Env_Var2=CapitalOneIsTheBest"

So everything in between "" above in setenv.sh gets set as environmental variables for your applications in Tomcat. To retrieve/use those environmental variables, use this in your Java (Spring) applications:

Ex1) String myWhatever = java.lang.System.getProperties().getProperty("My_Env_Var1"); 
Ex2) String env= System.getProperties().getProperty("My_Env_Var2");

To change the environmental variable (for example when you are writing unit tests), do this: 
System.setProperty("My_Env_Var1", "newEnv");